# Partial Fraction for rigorous understanding [ref. request]

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-fractions

I know usual techniques in partial fractions such as the ones described in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). But I don't understand how this process works in a precise manner.

I've seen in some complex analysis textbooks, discussions of partial fractions. So should I be aided by complex analysis to properly (and precisely) grasp the idea of partial fraction?

Please help!

Comment: It's just algebra. It's just a technique for breaking apart fractions, there really isn't anything more to discuss other than what's on wikipedia.

Comment: @avid19, we can ask things like: how does the partial fraction decomposition work in different fields? For instance, you can decompose things further in $\mathbb{C}(z)$ than in $\mathbb{R}(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a rational function $p(z)/q(z)$ where $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are polynomials, and the degree of $q$ is greater than that of $p$.
Factor $q(z) = \prod_{j=1}^m (z - r_j)^{d_j}$, where $r_j$ are complex numbers and $d_j$ positive integers.  Then the basic result is that we can write
$$ \dfrac{p(z)}{q(z)} = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^{d_j} \dfrac{c_{jk}}{(z - r_j)^k}$$
for some complex numbers $c_{jk}$.

The "complex analysis" proof of this goes like this: let $\sum_{k=1}^{d_j} c_{jk}/(z - r_j)^k$ be the principal part of $p(z)/q(z)$ at the pole $r_j$.  Let 
$f(z) = p(z)/q(z) - \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^{d_j} c_{jk}/(z - r_j)^k$.
Its singularities at the $r_j$ are removable; after removing those singularities, we have an entire function that goes to $0$ as $z \to \infty$.  By Liouville's theorem it is $0$.